# Trouble installing Yosemite on new SSD

Tags: macos, ssd

I have a problem where the Yosemite install does not see 240GB Mercury 6G Electra SSD during an install from the USB drive.

I'm using a USB thumb drive installer. It boots up fine. Except that when I get to the page where it asks you what drive to install to, all I see is the USB drive itself, and no SSD.

I triple checked that the SSD is installed correctly. I put it into the machine straight of the box, brand new.

Macbook Pro 8,1. Yosemite 10.10 installer.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When installing to a new drive, you first need to go into Disk Utility and partition the drive before it will be found as an installation target. Once you've created the partition, exit Disk Utility and restart the installation process. It should proceed as normal.

You'll want to use Mac OS Extended (Journaled) as your format type.